# external hard drive type is unknown in ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs, udf

I plugged my western digital elements 2tb external hdd into ubuntu machine.

Somehow my laptop hard drive got corrupted, and as soon as I connected my external drive it showed me as "CD_ROM"

Then I run a command

```
fsck -nf /dev/sda1
```

[image]

terminal out put

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me how to recover my hard drive in ubuntu?

Comment: It looks like you somehow managed to "install" a Windows ISO to that HDD (should have been in a USB stick, but Rufus and other tools allow for such mistakes) so no surprise it says "CD-ROM". And if my hypotheses is correct you may have lost whatever you had in that drive. There are recovery tools you may use though.

Comment: @MichaelBay you're right. i tried to install windows iso and i got stuck there. thanks for the relevant answer. i'll figure out to recover my data. thanks once againg